How can I prevent my phone asking to confirm any "When the last person leaves home" HomeKit automations?
I have a HomeKit automation set up to trigger "When the last person leaves home," and my understanding is that it should run automatically without any user interaction. However, every time I leave home, HomeKit prompts me to confirm whether I want to run the automation or not. If I don’t respond, the automation doesn’t execute.
This seems counterintuitive for an automation that's supposed to be automatic.
Are there ways I can ensure that the automation always runs without asking for a confirmation on iOS devices ?

I’m going to set aside with an edit the hypothetical “why did Apple design thusly” so we can focus on what you might be able to do to fix it.
